Databricks "Error: expected to have the absolute path of the object or directory"
I want to export a file from (Azure) Databricks workspace to local directory with the databricks-cli utility. This works:
databricks workspace list /mypath/test.md
ID               Type  Language  Path
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  FILE            /mypath/test.md

This fails:
databricks workspace export /mypath/test.md /targetpath/test.md
Error: expected to have the absolute path of the object or directory

This page details the same error but does not seem relevant to a Workspace query. Grateful for assistance.

Have also tried with dbfs: and dbfs:/Workspace prefixes - same error

Solved. You need to assign the output manually e.g.
databricks workspace export /mypath/test.md > /targetpath/test.md

Of course the documentation does not say what is returned from the call or include any examples.
